# Absent revision during a merge with the Eclipse CollabNet Merge client

Tags: svn, merge, subclipse, collabnet

I am trying to port a revision commited in a branch A to a branch B.

Here is the history of the branch A (r10629 is the revision I want to port to branch B):

[image: History of the branch A]

Usually, I merge the branches with the CollabNet Merge client in Eclipse (right click on the branch B project > Team > Merge...) by selecting the revisions I want to integrate.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

As you can see in the last screenshot, the revision 10629 is not displayed, unlike the others. What is wrong?

Comment: Check mergeinfo in target branch: it may already have 10629 as merged

Comment: @LazyBadger You are right. The `svn:mergeinfo` property contains the revision 10629. This revision had already been merged by another developper. Thank you! Perhaps you want to answer the question to earn the rep ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion has an API that is called here to determine what revisions are eligible to be merged.  From the command line, it would be something like:

$ svn mergeinfo --show-revs=eligible ^/branches/branchname .

The equivalent API for this command is used by the merge client to populate this display.  So yes the answer in the comments by @LazyBadger covers it. The fact that you did not see the revision is a sign that it had already been merged (or the revision touched a different branch then you thought).